# Accurate Element Selection Across Most Websites?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, automation

I am working on a project to create a no-code automation tool that aims to offer functionality similar to Selenium but without requiring the technical expertise to write scripts. My goal is to enable users to select and interact with elements across any website accurately.

The primary challenge I foresee is developing a system architecture in Javascript that can select elements on a webpage with extreme accuracy, regardless of the website's design or underlying technology. While I recognize that dynamic content can pose challenges, I'm focusing initially on static sites that don't change frequently.

Here's what I'd like some advice on:

1. Approaches to Element Selection: What methods can I use to ensure that the selected element is uniquely identified, even across various sites with different designs and structures?
2. Handling Text Formatting Across Sites: When interacting with different elements, especially text, on various websites, how can we ensure that the original formatting is retained? For example, if copying and pasting text between sites, is there a method to preserve the original fonts, colors, sizes, and other styling, regardless of the default settings or styles of the destination site? What might be the technical challenges and limitations in achieving this level of consistency across different browsers and websites?
3. Feasibility: If you believe this goal is unachievable, could you explain why? What are the key technical barriers that might prevent such a tool from working across 99% of sites, assuming the sites themselves are static and not ever-changing?

I appreciate any insights or concerns regarding this project. Thank you!

Here's what I've tried so far. My failures have brought me here.

Visual Element Selection:
Tried: Implementing a basic point-and-click interface to select elements visually.
Expecting: A simple and intuitive way for users to identify elements.
Challenges: Struggling with unique identification across various sites and designs.

Retaining Text Formatting:
Tried: Experimenting with the browser's clipboard API to capture and paste formatted text.
Expecting: Ability to copy and paste text with original styling intact.
Challenges: Inconsistent behavior across different browsers and complex formatting issues.

Comment: We were asked to develop something similar recently but we kept hitting dead ends and had to discard the idea altogether. We found this tool, [RainforesQA](https://help.rainforestqa.com/docs/visual-editor-test-faq#:~:text=The%20Rainforest%20Automation%20Service%20runs,And%20all%20without%20any%20code.), which I believe uses visual element selection and they have some VM's running on some servers to process the user input selection. Although, we never came close to building something even remotely close.

Comment: There is no universal solution. You would have to train an AI on thousands of sites and even then it would have occasionally fail because it doesn't have really "intelligence" so it won't be able to incorporate the changes into CSS of an arbitrary site. ShadowDOM might help with style isolation though.

Comment: I think the practical solution would be to have a number of scripts that can be chosen by the user to run.  They will each need to be created for a specific purpose... (and specific web sites)

Comment: @pcalkins I'm aiming for a more self-service type of automations software so that it can appeal a broader range of users. Are you a +1 for the idea that a generalized solution would be impossible?

Comment: @wOxxOm what do you think of the proposal from oturan that we could possibly use visual element selection to get around this problem. It's not necessary in my mind that the computer be intelligent, only that it selects the correct buttons, types the correct words and completes the correct tasks

Comment: @oturan thanks for the suggestion to use Rainforest QA. Do you mind sharing some of the dead ends you faced when exploring using Rainforest to build something similar? Would be great to hear some of the deadends you encountered during the discovery process

Comment: @Dianuna Just to list a few, 1) We were trying to build a web app, but it's impossible to open another website inside of an already opened one. IG a desktop app might work out but the suggestion quickly became out of scope. 2) Comparison with existing QA automation, a lot of use cases weren't simply achievable and the tool would've taken years to complete if we started taking the existing code and workarounds they had using Selenium.

Comment: nothing is impossible, but I think your requirements haven't really been defined yet.